# Storing multiple values from an SQL select statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ms-access

I have an SQL select query that will return multiple values, but I cannot find a way to store/access them. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and an Access database.

Below is my most recent attempt using a data table/grid view.

```
string now = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

//Establish and open new database connection.
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase32BITConnectionString"].ToString();
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

cmd.CommandText = String.Format ("select Rating from [RATINGS] where Today_Date like @now and Name like @name");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@now", now);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
cmd.Connection = con;
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
adapter.Fill(dt);
con.Close();
testGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

`name` is a variable passed into the  method. I don't necessarily need it stored in a data table, i just need to be able to access the results individually to average them (array?).

Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: `dt[0][0]` Should have the first value returned, `dt[0][1]` the second value, and so on.

Comment: The syntax for accecing the data is `dt[RowIndex][CellIndex]`